# sql column which contains a comma separate values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I combine multiple rows into one row and have a column which contains a comma separate values?

Example: Originally my SQLresult would return the following using a simple select script like

```
select order_no, item_no, item_description 
from orders...

order_no      item_no  item_description
1234          5        toaster
1234          6        hair dryer
```

Instead I would like to return the results into the below (having the `item_description` listed in the same order as the `item_nos`?

```
order_no     item_nos    item_descriptions
1234         5, 6        toaster, hair dryer
```

And could I return results like this?

```
order_no    item_nos_descriptions
1234        5 - toaster, 6 - hair dryer
```

By the way I'm using SQL 2008...

Comment: It smells like an awful design. Relational databases were *designed* to be normalized.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL? Sql-Server, MySQL , Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: I think this is not the schema but presentation/report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `group_concat` function ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)).

```
select 
  order_no,
  group_concat(item_no ORDER BY item_nos ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as item_nos,
  group_concat(item_description ORDER BY item_no ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
    as item_descriptions
from orders
group by order_no
```

will give something like this:

```
order_no     item_nos    item_descriptions
1234         5, 6        toaster, hair dryer
```

For the second form you requested, it would look something like this:

```
select 
  order_no,
  group_concat( concat(item_no,' - ',item_description 
    ORDER BY item_no ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
  as item_nos_descriptions
from orders
group by order_no
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005 and up, here's the way that I usually do it without using Recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
order_no int,
item_no int,
item_description nvarchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1234, 5, 'toaster')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1234, 6, 'hair dryer')

SELECT order_no,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(item_no AS VARCHAR) AS [text()]
            FROM @T As MyItem
            WHERE MyItem.order_no = MyTable.order_no
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '' ) AS item_nos,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(item_no AS VARCHAR) AS [text()]
            FROM @T As MyItem
            WHERE MyItem.order_no = MyTable.order_no
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '' ) AS item_descriptions
FROM @T AS MyTable
GROUP BY order_no
```

This yields:

```
Result Set (1 item)
order_no | item_nos | item_descriptions |
1234     | 5, 6         | 5, 6
```

The STUFF removes the last ', ' from the string.

The other way to do this is with recursive CTE, but I think the above will do...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should heed @pst if you can.

That said, most relational databases have a function to do exactly this. In MySQL it's `group_concat`. In Oracle it's `wm_concat`. In PostgreSQL it's `string_agg`. Notice it's rather unstandardized.

To use it, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT order_no, string_agg(item_description, ',') 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN line_items ON line_item.order_id = order.id
GROUP BY order_no;
```

Note that not all databases have a way to get from CSV back to rows. This is something I know PostgreSQL can do. I would expect Oracle to be able to do it, but haven't checked, and I'm fairly sure that MySQL cannot, but could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP_CONCAT` if you are using mySQL:

```
SELECT order_no, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(item_no ORDER BY item_no ASC SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(item_description ORDER BY item_no ASC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Orders
GROUP BY order_no
```

In this way you can keep the original normalized DB schema and still get the following result:

```
order_no     item_nos    item_descriptions
1234         5, 6        toaster, hair dryer
```

Comment: Hi, I'm currently running sql 2008, but I keep getting error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you could do this:

```
SELECT order_no, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(item_no,' - ',item_description) ORDER BY item_no ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Orders
GROUP BY order_no
```